# Open file selected using SAF in another application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-gallery, storage-access-framework

I have an application that allows choosing image that will be further processed using the Storage Access Framework. I want to allow the user to preview the image in another application that is installed on the system.

Simplified example (where I only receive the file and re-open it immediatelly):

```kotlin
val documentId = /* get from the SAF */
val uri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(null, documentId)
// uri == "content:/..."
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri).apply {
    type = "image/jpeg", // TODO read from the SAF-received file
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
})
```

However, the image is not opened by the gallery application – only the gallery main screen is shown. I think I need to grant permission to the receiving app somehow.

I want to **not assume** that the user has installed gallery app with some specific app ID. I want to show a chooser to the user when multiple apps can open the image.

Comment: You are building an uri. That should not be needed if the file was choosen as then you would have gotten a ready to use uri. You should better explain what you do.

Comment: `example (where I only receive the file and re-open it immediatelly):` ???? Receive the uri or file from who? You said the user choosed an image. You really have to write a better post. Dont use comments,,!

Comment: @blackapps, in my simplified example, I want to take the document ID (that I have successfully received from the file chooser) and open the file in my application. Later, I will add a button to the UI that will open the file.

Comment: Please show the code that lets the user choose a file and gives you a document id instead of an uri for a file.

Comment: It is unclear why you are taking the `Uri` that you get from SAF, extracting a document ID out of it, then are re-creating the `Uri`. Have you tried skipping that exercise and just using the original `Uri`? Also, is all of this happening in the same activity, because [your access lifetime is short](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).